# Get length of an empty or unset array when “nounset” option is in effect

Tags: bash

Due to the fact that Bash, when running in `set -o nounset` mode (aka `set -u`), may consider empty arrays as unset regardless of whether they have actually been assigned an empty value, care must be taken when attempting to expand an array — one of the workarounds is to check whether the array length is zero. Not to mention that getting the number of elements in an array is a common operation by itself.

While developing with Bash 4.2.47(1)-release in openSUSE 42.1, I accustomed to that getting array size with `${#ARRAY_NAME[@]}` succeeds when array is either empty or unset. However, while checking my script with Bash 4.3.46(1)-release in FreeBSD 10.3, it turned out that this operation may fail with generic “unbound variable” error message. Providing default value for expansion does not seem to work for array length. **Providing alternative command chains seems to work, but not inside a function called through a subshell expansion** — functions just exits after the first failure. What else can be of any help here?

Consider the following example:

```
function Size ()
{
    declare VAR="$1"
    declare REF="\${#${VAR}[@]}"
    eval "echo \"${REF}\" || echo 0" 2>/dev/null || echo 0
}

set -u
declare -a MYARRAY

echo "size: ${#MYARRAY[@]}"
echo "size: ${#MYARRAY[@]-0}"
echo "Size: $(Size 'MYARRAY')"
echo -n "Size: "; Size 'MYARRAY'
```

In openSUSE environment, all `echo` lines output `0`, as expected. In FreeBSD, the same outcome is only possible when the array is explicitly assigned an empty value: `MYARRAY=()`; otherwise, both inline queries in the first two lines fail, the third line just outputs `Size:` (meaning that the expansion result is empty), and only the last line succeeds completely thanks to the outer `|| echo 0` — however passing the result through to the screen is not what is usually intended when trying to obtain array length.

Here is the summary of my observations:

```
                                    Bash 4.2  Bash 4.3
                                    openSUSE  FreeBSD

counting elements of unset array       OK      FAILED
counting elements of empty array       OK        OK

content expansion of unset array     FAILED    FAILED
content expansion of unset array(*)    OK        OK
content expansion of empty array     FAILED    FAILED
content expansion of empty array(*)    OK        OK
    (* with fallback value supplied)
```

To me, that looks pretty inconsistent. Is there any real future-proof and cross-platform solution for that?

Comment: Please add output of `echo $-` to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus It is `huB` in both systems when running a script, `himBH` when in command line.

Comment: Why not just do `set +u`, then do the necessary checks, then `set -u`?

Comment: @WilliamPursell That seemed an ugly solution to me, but turns out to be the only viable with acceptable performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a temporary solution, I followed the route suggested by @william-pursell and just unset the `nounset` option during the query:

```
function GetArrayLength ()
{
    declare ARRAY_NAME="$1"
    declare INDIRECT_REFERENCE="\${#${ARRAY_NAME}[@]}"
    case "$-" in
    *'u'*)
        set +u
        eval "echo \"${INDIRECT_REFERENCE}\""
        set -u
        ;;
    *)
        eval "echo \"${INDIRECT_REFERENCE}\""
        ;;
    esac
}
```

(Using `if` instead of `case` leads to negligibly slower execution on my test machines. Moreover, `case` allows matching additional options easily if that would become necessary sometime.)

I also tried exploiting the fact that content expansion (with fallback or replacement value) usually succeeds even for unset arrays:

```
function GetArrayLength ()
{
    declare ARRAY_NAME="$1"
    declare INDIRECT_REFERENCE="${ARRAY_NAME}[@]"
    if [[ -z "${!INDIRECT_REFERENCE+isset}" ]]; then
        echo 0
    else
        INDIRECT_REFERENCE="\${#${ARRAY_NAME}[@]}"
        eval "echo \"${INDIRECT_REFERENCE}\""
    fi
}
```

However, it turns out that Bash does not optimize `${a[@]+b}` expansion, as execution time clearly increases for larger arrays — although being the smallest one for empty or unset arrays.

Nevertheless, if anyone has a better solution, fell free to post other answers.

Answer (score 1):

There are known (documented) differences between the Linux and BSD flavors of `bash`.  I would suggest writing your code as per the POSIX standard.  You can start here for more information ->  www2.opengroup.org.

With that in mind, you can start `bash` with the `--posix` command-line option or you can execute the command `set -o posix` while `bash` is running.  Either will cause `bash` to conform to the POSIX standard.

The above suggestion will increase the probability of cross-platform consistency.

Comment: Nice point. However, in this particular case I see no difference between `posix off` and `posix on`. Same holds true for other discrepancies I noticed, such as regular expression matching.